# Array multiplication function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am trying to multiply each individual number in an array with another array of different length but have only been able to accomplish this by a long-winded method.

array 1: `J7:J25`   array 2: `B62:B68`

```
{=J7*B62:B68 +J8*B62:B68 + ... +J25*B62:B68}
```

I need to do this multiple times for several very long arrays. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

NOT TESTED IN Excel 2013, but please try:

```
=SUM(MMULT(J7:J25,TRANSPOSE(B62:B80)))
```

with B69:B80 padded with `0`s and entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Good answer, but actually Array Formula is not required

Comment: Works in 2010 with and without CSE